# HTML - How can I label these hyperlinks and DRY up the repeated 'Companies'

Tags: html, user-interface

I am struggling to find the right label for the hyperlinks, currently called companies.
Right now it look like the table below.  Companies is a hyperlink to a page that shows all those companies (in this table, either 1, 12 or 26 companies).

The value in each row for each industry's name (Accounting , Advertising, etc.) is a link to details about that industry so I can't use that.

However I do not like the way `Companies` repeats itself. Yuch. I would rather have a heading of Companies and then a link to see the list of those companies.

But what would I label that hyperlink with? That's not just being repeated the same way each time, the way `Companies` has been in the example?

```
Industry_Name         
Accounting      Companies (1)  
Advertising     Companies (1)  
Art             Companies (1)  
Assets          Companies (1)  
Audio           Companies (12)  
Causes          Companies (1)  
Clubs           Companies (1)  
Consulting      Companies (26)
```

This example seems very specific but it is a fairly common pattern I have seen several times and I would welcome the community's suggestion on good approaches.

Please think outside the box and consider other graphical elements if they would help.

Comment: list: consulting(26), assets(1), etc?

Comment: Thanks Radagaisus, sorry, I updated the question to show that the Industry name is already a hyperlink, so the problem is I need TWO hyperlinks, what to name them both.

Comment: What is your model? That's what's going to tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Following your latest edit and comment, what is it you're trying to get to? Can you provide an (edited) example in your question? Do you not want `Companies(x)`? Do you want something else? What other data on those elements do you have that will allow you to expand on that information?

Comment: Hi Jared, Industry has_many Companies and Company belongs_to Industry.

Comment: Hi Jard, the attributes for Industry are just name and timestamps.  For Company there are a bunch more but they are items like web_site and stuff so I didn't see how they would help but maybe they could. I guess I am asking for others to see what I can't so that is a good question for exploration. Thank You.

Comment: This might be a better suited conversation for http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is this:

```
Industry_Name | Companies
-------------------------
Accounting    |   (1) 
Advertising   |   (1)  
Art           |   (1)  
Assets        |   (1)  
Audio         |   (12)  
Causes        |   (1)  
Clubs         |   (1)  
Consulting    |   (26)
```

Make the numbers clickable and clearly indicate visually that they are clickable (color and underline like links, use a fairly large font, etc)

Another option is this:

```
Industry 
-------------------------
Accounting (1) [details] 
Advertising (1) [details]
Art (1) [details]
Assets (1) [details]
Audio (12) [details]
Causes (1) [details]
Clubs (1) [details]
Consulting (26) [details]
```

with the industry name and number linking to the Companies detail, and the [detail] link (which could be an icon rather than the text repeating) linking to the industry description.

I don't know enough about your use case to know which would be better, but from the info you've provided I'd probably go with one of these two.

Edit: Adding a third option. I like this one better, actually.

```
Industry_Name |               Companies
------------------------------------------------------
Accounting    | [ABC Corp]
Advertising   | [AdCo]  
Art           | [ArtOGram]  
Assets        | [StuffCo]  
Audio         | [SoundCo, Bass Inc, and 10 others]  
Causes        | [WeHelp]  
Clubs         | [ClubNet]  
Consulting    | [Foo Cons, Baz Cons, and 24 others]
```

Comment: That's great Ian I appreciate you taking time on this.  I have considered the first option but I just don't like the idea of hyperlinking (1), y'know? It just looks ugly. I would prefer to give better semantic meaning to the link somehow.  The second option ends up repeating 'details' instead of 'Companies' so doesn't really meet my need to not have a repeating element that way (I know the hyperlink moved but the essence is the same).

Comment: Sometimes you just can't avoid repeating an element. I'll be interested to see if someone else comes up with a brilliant solution - and it's great to be asking - but I think this may be a case where you get to pick WHAT to duplicate. One important consideration is how much data would each be - tooltips could be used for the "details about the company", for instance. Or you could list the first few items and a (more) under details. I'll edit that one in to my answer as another option.

Comment: i like the third option!  With my new jQuery skills I think I would then underline all the content's between the [] (to indicate link) and then have a div open up listing the other companies.  So I guess I would populate all the div's first and then hide them and then reveal when the [] content is click on.  Or hyperlink each company, plus 'others' and have 'others' reveal the div and again then each company is a link for individual detail.  Anyway +35 for thinking outside the box!.